# Определение наcтроек уровня микрофона

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо определить уровень микрофона равен нулю или он выше. Откуда можно получить данные (желательно используя javascript)?

Comment: давая такие задания, не стоит забывать указывать сумму в $ за его выполнение

Comment: Для определения работает ли микрофон есть API getUserMedia. В данном случае есть ли  какое то аналогичное решения для данной проблемы?